# ExtjsS 4.2. How to switch betwen remote and local queryMode in combobox?

Tags: extjs

I started a thread in Sencha forum, but still didn't get any result. So, the question is how to change dynamically queryMode configuration of the combobox? I've read something on the web and found tips to use

`Ext.apply(Ext.getCmp('mycombo'),{queryMode:'local'})`

But this has ho effect. To understand what I want, let me give you a concrete example. I have a table with cities, this table has two columns - countries and cities. queryMode is set 'remote', so when the user starts typing 'Russia', it upploads rows of pairs (country, city). In this case the store becomes 'Russia Moscow, Russia Orel, etc'. From this moment when the store is loaded I want to make it static, so that when the user continues typing 'Russia Mo...' there will be no server calls, the current static store will be just filtered according to what was typed.

Answer (score -1):

```
Ext.getCmp('mycombo').queryMode = "local";
```

Comment: Actually, it was the very first thing I did. But it also has no effect. queryMode becomes local de jure, but not de facto, since if you continue typing in the combobox, you will still see server requests.